# Batch script - rename file based on words

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

Sorry i am new to batch script programming.

**Question**

I want to rename some files in a windows directory.

The sample files are as following (size is just an indicator):

```
PP123_MQ_large.png    <- size: 30kb
PP123_MQ_medium.png   <- size: 50kb 
PP123_MQ_small.png    <- size: 60kb

PP666_MQ.png          <- size: 68kb

PP234_MQ3_small.png   <- size: 31kb

PP789_MQ2_large.png   <- size: 15kb
```

For files that has word `large`, i want to rename it into `small`.

For files that has word `small`, i want to rename it into `large`.

For files that has word `medium`, i want it remain UNTOUCHED.

For files that has NO word `small` or `large`, i want it remain UNTOUCHED.

**Expected Result**

```
PP123_MQ_small.png     <- size: 30kb  changed to small
PP123_MQ_medium.png    <- size: 50kb  remain untouch because is medium
PP123_MQ_large.png     <- size: 60kb  changed to large

PP666_MQ.png           <- size: 68kb  remain untouch because no small or large

PP234_MQ3_large.png    <- size: 31kb  changed to large

PP789_MQ2_small.png    <- size: 15kb  changed to small
```

**Problem**

Following is my batch script:

```
cd C:\Users\mydir
ren *_large.png *_tempsmall.png
ren *_small.png *_large.png
ren *_tempsmall.png *_small.png
```

But for file that has only `small`, like `PP234_MQ3_small.png`, it will generate extra file `PP234_MQ3_large.png`.

For file that has only `large`, like `PP789_MQ2_large.png`, it will generate extra file `PP789_MQ2_small.png`.

I just want to rename existing files, and not to generate extra files, how can i improve my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a go:

```
cd /d "C:\users\mydir"
ren *_small.png *_large.png_tmp
ren *_large.png *_small.png_tmp
ren *.png_tmp *.png
```

We move everything `small` to `large`, with a `_tmp` to the extension and vice versa. Then we just rename all the files removing `_tmp`

Additionally, as a safery feature, use `cd /d` as shown above and even better if it is specifically your own profile replace `cd /d "c:\Users\mydir"` with `cd /d "%userprofile%"`

Comment: sorry was trying out other methods myself using `if-else`, yup it works, thanks